# use custom calendar with swift project

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I need to implement my project custom calendar but I'm new to ios and do not know how to do it! I have read various articles but I realized that I myself do not do it! maybe there's some kind of library allows to make eto.Spasibo for any help!

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/SVCalendar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this cocoa pods it is very convenient and easy to use JTCalendar

Basic usage

You have to create two views in your UIViewController.

The first view is JTCalendarMenuView, it represents the months.

The second view is JTCalendarContentView, the calendar itself.

Your UIViewController must implement JTCalendarDataSource

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "JTCalendar.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<JTCalendarDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JTCalendarMenuView *calendarMenuView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JTCalendarContentView *calendarContentView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) JTCalendar *calendar;

@end
JTCalendar is used to coordinate calendarMenuView and calendarContentView.

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.calendar = [JTCalendar new];

    [self.calendar setMenuMonthsView:self.calendarMenuView];
    [self.calendar setContentView:self.calendarContentView];
    [self.calendar setDataSource:self];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.calendar reloadData]; // Must be call in viewDidAppear
}

- (BOOL)calendarHaveEvent:(JTCalendar *)calendar date:(NSDate *)date
{
    return NO;
}

- (void)calendarDidDateSelected:(JTCalendar *)calendar date:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
}

@end
```

For more informations about how organize events by date see the Example project.

https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar